# How many fragment can be added to a single activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any limit to adding fragments in a single activity? if yes, then what is limit?

Comment: But he told me there is limit i said no we can add multiple then he said can you add 10 k fragments?

Comment: If you have the memory...

Answer (score 1):

There is no official guideline regarding the limit of fragments that can be added to an activity. You can have as many as you need and looks logical for your app.

Answer (score 0):

So far, no limit for number of fragments in activity

Just remember that all Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Comment: hope it was helpful